# jQuery Datepicker position issue on FireFox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Somehow jQuery datepicker is displaying at the top of window instead of under input field on the FireFox when IE and Chrome works fine. There is no additional CSS or jQuery - just vanilla KnockoutJS with jQuery + jQuery UI and a default theme from there.

[image]

Code for datepicker looks like

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        maxDate: "0",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        yearRange: "-123:+nn"
    });
});
```

And HTML

```
<label>DOB:</label><input id="datepicker" data-bind="textInput: birthdate">
```

Working example here http://ouyanews.us/FFtest.html - just change FF browser window to get Suffix label into second row then it should to re-create issue.

Any clue what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a working example? It's really hard to help without it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bkomzL2s/

Comment: @Dekel - OP updated with a working example link and how to reproduce issue on FF

Comment: @Barmar - issue is not present on JSfiddle as it uses an iframe to present an output

Comment: I just tried FFtest.html in FF 53.0.3 on El Capitan and it worked fine.

Comment: @Barmar - I have tested it with 3 different computers from 3 different locations and I can reproduce issue.

Comment: I just tried FF 53 on three different operating systems on BrowserStack and couldn't reproduce it. I tried Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and OS X Sierra.

Comment: Windows 10 screenshot: https://snag.gy/oQWiYt.jpg

Comment: Have you tried disabling browser extensions, to see if they're related?

Comment: @Barmar it works when you have full window (as is on your screenshot) but when you will resize that way as Suffix label and input filed will collapse to new row then you need to try datepicker on FF

Comment: You need to add that detail to the question. For some reason, jQuery is setting the style of the datepicker DIV to `position: absolute; top: 0;`.

Comment: @Barmar I have added that detail to my question yesterday evening. Also as I have mentioned jQuery and jQuery UI are default - no modification there. But I will take a look on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

replace `datepicker` code with below

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "0",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    yearRange: "-123:+nn",
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: $("#datepicker").offset().top + 25,
                left: $("#datepicker").offset().left
            });
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

In `beforeShow` function(called just before the datepicker is displayed) you can set top or left position of datepicker.

```js
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 maxDate: "0",
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 showOn: "both",
 buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.png",
 buttonImageOnly: true,
 buttonText: "Select date",
 yearRange: "-123:+nn",
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: $("#datepicker").offset().top+25,
                left: $("#datepicker").offset().left
            });
        }, 0);
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<label>DOB:</label><input id="datepicker" data-bind="textInput: birthdate">
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            var rect = input.getBoundingClientRect();
            setTimeout(function () {
            //Set your datepicker possition
             inst.dpDiv.css({ top: rect.top + 40, left: rect.left + 0 });
            }, 0);
        }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <form>
    <input class="datepicker" name="date2" type="text">
    </form>
```

You can customize pop-up position with applying custom styling to the inst.dpDiv. Hope this will help you.

Greetings!